# predict newdata with NA for smooth.splines

Tags: r, regression, predict, spline, smoothing

I am doing a `smooth.spline()` fit and afterwards a prediction with the fit. I have the problem that my newdata has some NAs. Now I'm trying to get NAs for the prediction too. But I don't get it to work.

I have made up some reproducible code to illustrate my problem.
I want my newdata and my prediction to be of the same length. I did not have this problem for example when using `predict` with a `loess` model. It automatically puts NA to `y` if `x` is NA. I saw this question for the prediction of other models (`lm`, `glm`,..) but the answers there by setting `na.action=na.exclude` does not work for me.

```
x <- c(1:5, NA, 7:12, NA, 15:19, 22:23)
y <- rnorm(length(x))
y[which(is.na(x))] <-NA
length(y) #20

x.new <- c(x[1:18],20,21,x[19:20])
length(x.new) #22

spl <- smooth.spline(x=x[!is.na(y)], y=y[!is.na(y)], spar=0.001)
spl.pr <- predict(spl, x=x.new[!is.na(x.new)], na.action=na.exclude)
length(spl.pr$y) #20
```

My predict command also won't work if I don't exclude NAs right inside the `predict` E.g. :

```
> spl.pr <- predict(spl, x=x.new, na.action=na.exclude)
Error in double(n) : vector size cannot be NA
```

I hope I made my problem understandable. Help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predict` behaves differently for different model class. There is no `na.action` for `stats:::predict.smooth.spline` and `stats:::predict.smooth.spline.fit`. So you have to predict at non NA values only.

```
spl.pr <- rep(NA, length(x.new))
spl.pr[!is.na(x.new)] <- predict(spl, x = x.new[!is.na(x.new)])$y
```

Note that `spl.pr` is not a list with `$x` and `$y`, but a numerical vector.

---

> Ok I suspected that. I was unsure though because I did not get an error message when using `na.action = na.exclude` within the command. Your recommended way around it works well, thank you!

@Katharina Haha, you did not get error because there is a `...` argument in `predict()` function. So basically you can pass in whatever unused argument to it. Try this

```
predict(spl, x = 5, this.answer.is.useful = TRUE)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Ok I suspected that. I was unsure though because I did not get an error message when using `na.action=na.exclude`within the command. Your recommended way around it works well, thank you! (I upvoted your answer, unfortunately it does not show in public until I earned a certain amount of badges- 10 I think; edit: it seemed to work now)